# Topology of $GL_n(F)$ for a discrete field.

Tags: general-topology

Is $GL_n(F)$ the set of invertible matrices open in $\mathbb M_n(F)$ for every field $F$? I think not because the proof relies on the fact that the determinant is continuous so since   $F-0$ is open in $F$, its preimage $GL_n(F)$ must be open in $ \mathbb M_n(F)$, now what if the field $F$ was discrete, in this case $F-0$ is not open since $\{0\}$ is not closed in $F$?

Comment: If $F$ is discrete then all subsets are closed.

Comment: All of this really depends on the topology you put on your field. Of course, if $\{0\}$ is not closed, its inverse image under a continuous map may not be closed, but at the same time, the determinant may not be a continuous map anymore...

Answer (score 2):

If $F$ is any *Hausdorff topological field*, then the natural topology on $\mathrm{Mat}_n(F)$ for any $n$ is just the product topology by identifying it (via any choice of order of the entries) with $F^{n^2}$. Then $\mathrm{GL}_n(F)$ is identified with the subset of $F^{n^2}$ where the determinant $\det$ (a polynomial in the entries of the matrix) is non-zero. Since polynomial functions on $F^{n^2}$ are continuous (because $F$ is a topological field), the set $\det^{-1}(F\setminus\{0\})$ is open (because $F$ is Hausdorff, $F\setminus\{0\}$ is open). So indeed $\mathrm{GL}_n(F)$ is an open subset of $\mathrm{Mat}_n(F)$.

Any field with the discrete topology is a Hausdorff topological field, so the answer to that part of your question is yes. Without putting a topology on $F$, it doesn't make sense to ask whether or not $\mathrm{GL}_n(F)$ is open in anything.

Comment: what if $F=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$?

Comment: Dear @palio, Did you read the last remark of my answer? You have to specify a topology before asking this question. The only (Hausdorff) topology on $F$ is the discrete topology, and then the answer is "yes."